# Beginner Questions for Python

Tags: python

Why is the following true when it is entered into python?

```
>>> 'cat' != 'dog'
True
>>> 'dog' != 'cat'
True
```

Is there a reason for this? Or perhaps part of the python programming?

Comment: Because 'cat' does not equal 'dog'. Nor does 'dog' equal 'cat'. Communitive property.

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: @Johnny -- You still remember the commutative property? I forgot that in 3rd grade all those years ago :-)

Comment: @Xilpex I'm not exactly an adult so it's still fresh enough enough in my mind, haha.

Comment: @Johnny -- Not an adult either :-)

Answer (score 0):

`'cat' != 'dog'` means that `'cat'` is not equal to `'dog'`
If you want to compare types, then

```py
type('cat') != type('dog')
```

is `False`, becuase `cat` is a `string` and `dog` is a `string`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you expected to see `False`?

In Python (and many other languages) [`!=` means "not-equal-to"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons), while `==` means "equal-to". So `'cat' != 'dog'` asks Python "is the string `cat` not-equal-to the string `dog`?" which is `True` - they are not-equal-to one another. The inverse, `'cat' == 'dog'` could be read as "is the string `cat` *equal-to* `dog`?" which is `False` - they are *not* equal-to one another.

If this is confusing or surprising to you, look into topics like "[formal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic#Formal_logic)", "symbolic logic", or "[Boolean logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra). Most programming languages share a common notion of truth and falsity that draws from these concepts.